# How to get the x and y of a widget in GtkFixed in C++ with Gtk+ 3.0?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3

I want to place a GtkLabel relevant to the position of a GtkButton. How do I get the position of the button, x and y seperately ?

Comment: Gtk+ 3 as I added to the title

Comment: `GtkFixed` runs counter to the ethos of GTK+ and effective UI design, which favour relative (not _relevant_) positioning. They say: `For most applications, you should not use this! It keeps you from having to learn about the other containers but results in broken applications [...] truncated text, overlapping widgets [...] not usable in right-to-left languages` If you want relative positioning... then use a relative-positioning container. But if you _insist_, why not just put the `Button` in the `Fixed`, at known coordinates, then put a `Label` 'relative' to those known coords of the `Button`?

Comment: I might as well say that the answer is to use the child properties `x` and `y`; see the GtkContainer documentation for how to query child properties.